# .htaccess rewrite rule with parameters

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a lot of urls in the following format.

```
index.php?option=com_letflat&task=view&id=42

index.php?option=com_letflat&task=view&task=ajaxmap
```

I want to rewrite all urls that contain option=com_letflat to the root of the domain, ie http://www.example.com

I have tried dozens of different things, and none seem to work.
I have got as far as this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)option=com_letflat [NC]
RewriteRule ^index.php(.*)  http://www.example.com [R=301,L]
```

But it doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)option=com_letflat(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php /? [R=301,L]
```

Just make sure this is very first rule in your .htaccess